# Is it off-topic to ask about pricing UX consulting services?

Tags: discussion

I'm shifting my pricing model from hourly ("cost plus") to value pricing. Because design services are unique, I'd value this community's input on assessing their value. However, if my question is off-topic, I'll take it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is off-topic, yes. That's not a UX question, it's a business one. The question is: "How much should I charge for {thing}" The crux of the question is 'how much should I charge for...', it isn't about UX.

It's also very subjective, will be different for every person.

Now if your question were about whether *users* prefer to pay hourly or by value for a particular service, or about how you should inform users that you are changing your pricing policy then that would be more of a UX one, but if you're just asking how much *you personally* should charge for a service, then no.

Questions here should be based on a particular UX issue that you are struggling to solve (i.e. you don't know how to get the user to complete a certain task), and the answers will be from people saying 'you can solve that by doing X'. Often there is one correct answer to such questions, or if not there are answers that are better than others as they get you closer to your ideal solution.